# Algorithm to find if sine of any given angle is rational

Tags: trigonometry, rational-functions

Given any angle, can I check if the sine of that angle is going to be rational?

What more are my possibilities? Can I check if cosine is rational? Can I generate a formula for all such angles where sine is rational? Cosine is rational? Both are rational?

Note that my question does not require the angle itself to be rational, so Niven's theorem is probably a digression.

Comment: How is the angle given -- that is, which kind of representation of the angle should the algorithm you're looking for take as _input_?

Comment: If the angle is a rational fraction of one rotation, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem

Comment: @Troposphere How does it matter? Anyways for the sake of informative completeness, suppose we're putting in the angle in radians.

Comment: @TomKern No I'm not putting constraints on the angle. I mean not in the sense *I won't put any constraints!* I am searching for a more general analysis if it exists.

Comment: An _algorithm_ needs to have input that is a finite sequence of symbols. You can't express arbitrary real numbers as input to an algorithm -- there's not enough different finite sequences of symbols for that. So before you can ask for an algorithm, you need to choose a set of values you can represent, and probably also a concrete scheme for representing them (unless it is obvious from the definition of the _set_ of represented values how we could do it).

Comment: The trouble this is leading up to is that if your input representation is approximate in any way, then the answer is always, "in the interval of angles represented by this approximation, some of them have rational sines, and some are irrational". Not very enlightening. But on the other hand, if you pick a mere _subset_ of all possible angles to represent exactly, then all the choices I can immediately imagine would lead to a result more or less like Niven's theorem -- that is, you would learn nothing at all about the huge majority of angles that are _not_ in your representable set.